# Error when trying to send email with firebase trigger email extension

Tags: firebase, email

I am trying to send emails within certain firebase functions. When I do, the email appears in the database as expected, but with this error

> Error: 69155816175488:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I believe that the smtp server is set up correctly.